# Iterating over a hash with arrays as value

Tags: ruby, hash

I am asking a user for key `currentline` and value `currentstation` in order to compare it against a hash, and display which line to travel.

```
mtahash = {
  n: ["timesq", "34thn", "28thn", "23rdn", "Union_Square", "8th"],
  l: ["8th", "6th", "Union_Square", "3rd", "1st"],
  s: ["Grand Central", "33rds", "28th", "23rds", "Union Square", "Astor Place"]
}

puts "Please enter your current station"
current_station = gets.chomp
puts "Please enter your current line"
current_line = gets.chomp

mtahash.each do |key, value|
  if key == current_line && value == current_station
    puts "got it"
  else
    puts "fish"
  end
end
```

My code outputs `fish` three times regardless of the input.

Comment: its a string and should be any value from the hash

Comment: I am very new to learning coding and ruby to be specific - its so much to learn but I am learning and I will get there eventually. :)

Answer (score 1):

A `value` in this iteration is an array. You should be checking if it includes station name, not if it's equal to it. Also transform key to string with `key.to_s` (it's a symbol now):

```
 mtahash.each do |key, value|
   if key.to_s == current_line && value.include?(current_station)
     puts "got it"
   else
     puts "fish"
   end
 end
```

Comment: fixed the typo.

Comment: This is going to run once for each key in `mtahash`.  For example, `current_line = 'n', current_station = '8th'  => got it \n fish \n fish`. Is this the intended functionality?

Comment: @Tom it's just as close to the original solution as possible.

Comment: @mrzasa Was just curious what fahz would say he was looking for. Nothing against your answer.

Comment: for now, yes it the one time thing to run @Tom

Answer (score 0):

`each` will iterate for each key value (even if one match is found) but `detect` will stop once it got found match.

I think keys for hash is unique so `detect` is better than using `each`

```
mtahash.detect { |k, v| k.to_s == current_line && v.include?(current_station) } ? 'got it' : 'fish'
```

Reduce iterations.

```
 > mtahash = {:n=>["timesq", "34thn", "28thn", "23rdn", "Union_Square", "8th"], :l=>["8th", "6th", "Union_Square", "3rd", "1st"], :s=>["Grand Central", "33rds", "28th", "23rds", "Union Square", "Astor Place"]} 
 >   current_line, current_station = 'l', '3rd'
 => ["l", "3rd"] 

 > mtahash.detect { |k, v| k.to_s == current_line && v.include?(current_station) } ? 'got it' : 'fish'
 => "got it" 

 > current_line, current_station = 'l', '43rd'
 => ["l", "43rd"] 

 > mtahash.detect { |k, v| k.to_s == current_line && v.include?(current_station) } ? 'got it' : 'fish'
 => "fish"
```

Comment: This is understandable line of code but still doesn;t work. The output is always fish 3 times no matter what input is

Comment: @fahz it is impossible what you said, check updated log in my answer

Comment: it is not working for sure at my end .. doesn;t give any output except for fish :(((((((

Comment: @fahz because you did not provide what your hash have! e.g. `n` & `23rdn`

Comment: what does that mean? Hash is defined at the top already.. also I am trying the code without user input I am just hard coding it still it not working - what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @fahz you need to post your `current_line`, `current_station` here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186361/discussion-between-fahz-and-ray).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to convert `to_sym` ([String#to_sym](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-to_sym)) the user input for current_line, since the hash keys are symbols.

Then check if the hash has that key ([Hash#has_key](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F)).

Finally access the hash by key and check if the array includes ([Array#include](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)) the `current_station`, since values of the hash are arrays.

This is just a snippet as example.

```
current_station = "timesq" # gets.chomp
current_line = "n".to_sym  # gets.chomp.to_sym <--- note .to_sym

if mtahash.has_key? current_line
    if mtahash[current_line].include? current_station
      then puts "got it"
      else puts "fish"
    end
  else puts "no line"
end
```

---

Even better, invert the input sequence, check the `mtahash.has_key?` after the user enters the line, if true go asking for the station.